# cs50 filter(more comfortable) - Image filters in C

Tags: c, image

I've been taking cs50 for about under a month now and I've finally finished with "filter" in pset4. The code passes all the green checks on check50. Our task was to implement functions in `helpers.c` so that a user can apply grayscale, reflection, blur, or edge detection filters to their images. We were asked not to modify any of the function signatures or any files other than `helpers.c`.

My question is, how I could refactor the code in the edge detection block so that it is shorter with less repeated code? If there is a solution involving pointers, I'd much prefer that if possible! Any tips on other blocks are welcome as well. Thank you!

Here are links to the outline of cs50/pset4/filter and information on the sobel operator: 
[cs50/pset4/filter](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/more/) 
[Sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)

Files provided that we were asked not to modify:
*bmp.h*

> ```
> // BMP-related data types based on Microsoft's own
>
> #include <stdint.h>
>
> /**
>  * Common Data Types
>  *
>  * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++
>  * primitive data types.
>  *
>  * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx.
>  * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
>  */
> typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
> typedef uint32_t DWORD;
> typedef int32_t  LONG;
> typedef uint16_t WORD;
>
> /**
>  * BITMAPFILEHEADER
>  *
>  * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
>  * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
>  *
>  * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(VS.85).aspx.
>  */
> typedef struct
> {
>     WORD   bfType;
>     DWORD  bfSize;
>     WORD   bfReserved1;
>     WORD   bfReserved2;
>     DWORD  bfOffBits;
> } __attribute__((__packed__))
> BITMAPFILEHEADER;
>
> /**
>  * BITMAPINFOHEADER
>  *
>  * The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure contains information about the
>  * dimensions and color format of a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
>  *
>  * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(VS.85).aspx.
>  */
> typedef struct
> {
>     DWORD  biSize;
>     LONG   biWidth;
>     LONG   biHeight;
>     WORD   biPlanes;
>     WORD   biBitCount;
>     DWORD  biCompression;
>     DWORD  biSizeImage;
>     LONG   biXPelsPerMeter;
>     LONG   biYPelsPerMeter;
>    DWORD  biClrUsed;
>     DWORD  biClrImportant;
> } __attribute__((__packed__))
> BITMAPINFOHEADER;
>
> /**
>  * RGBTRIPLE
>  *
>  * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
>  * red, green, and blue.
>  *
>  * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx.
>  */
> typedef struct
> {
>     BYTE  rgbtBlue;
>     BYTE  rgbtGreen;
>     BYTE  rgbtRed;
> } __attribute__((__packed__))
> RGBTRIPLE;
> ```

*filter.c*

> ```
> #include <getopt.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> #include "helpers.h"
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>
>     // Define allowable filters
>     char *filters = "begr";
>
>     // Get filter flag and check validity
>     char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
>     if (filter == '?')
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Invalid filter.\n");
>         return 1;
>     }
>
>     // Ensure only one filter
>     if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Only one filter allowed.\n");
>         return 2;
>     }
>
>     // Ensure proper usage
>     if (argc != optind + 2)
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Usage: filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
>         return 3;
>     }
>
>     // Remember filenames
>     char *infile = argv[optind];
>     char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];
>
>     // Open input file
>     FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
>     if (inptr == NULL)
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
>         return 4;
>     }
>
>     // Open output file
>     FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
>     if (outptr == NULL)
>     {
>         fclose(inptr);
>         fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
>         return 5;
>     }
>
>     // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
>     BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
>     fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
>
>     // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
>     BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
>     fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
>
>     // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
>     if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
>         bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
>     {
>         fclose(outptr);
>         fclose(inptr);
>         fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
>         return 6;
>     }
>
>     int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
>     int width = bi.biWidth;
>
>     // Allocate memory for image
>     RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
>     if (image == NULL)
>     {
>         fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory to store image.\n");
>         fclose(outptr);
>         fclose(inptr);
>         return 7;
>     }
>
>     // Determine padding for scanlines
>     int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
>
>     // Iterate over infile's scanlines
>     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
>     {
>         // Read row into pixel array
>         fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);
>
>         // Skip over padding
>         fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
>     }
>
>     // Filter image
>     switch (filter)
>     {
>         // Blur
>         case 'b':
>             blur(height, width, image);
>             break;
>
>         // Edges
>         case 'e':
>             edges(height, width, image);
>             break;
>
>         // Grayscale
>         case 'g':
>             grayscale(height, width, image);
>             break;
>
>         // Reflect
>         case 'r':
>             reflect(height, width, image);
>             break;
>     }
>
>     // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
>     fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);
>
>     // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
>     fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);
>
>     // Write new pixels to outfile
>     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
>     {
>         // Write row to outfile
>         fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, outptr);
>
>         // Write padding at end of row
>         for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
>         {
>             fputc(0x00, outptr);
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Free memory for image
>     free(image);
>
>     // Close infile
>     fclose(inptr);
>
>     // Close outfile
>     fclose(outptr);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

**My** *helpers.c*

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// Prototypes
void swap(RGBTRIPLE *a, RGBTRIPLE *b);

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Iterate through the height or also known as each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through the width or also known as each pixel/column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Calculate the average of the R, G, and B values and round to nearest integer
            int average = round(((double) image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (double) image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (double) image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3);
            // Set the values of R, G, and B to the average, making them the same, to produce the correct shade of gray
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Iterate through the height or also known as each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through the width or also known as each pixel/column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Perform swap up until the middle
            if (j < width / 2)
            {
                swap(&image[i][j], &image[i][width - (j + 1)]);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Function to swap two elements
void swap(RGBTRIPLE *a, RGBTRIPLE *b)
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Initialize copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    // Make a copy of image to preserve original values
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Iterate through the height or also known as each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through the width or also known as each pixel/column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Variable that counts how many numbers added to arrive at the sum
            int count = 0;

            // Sum variables for each colour
            double sum_blue = 0;
            double sum_green = 0;
            double sum_red = 0;

            // Loop to check the surrounding pixels within 1 column and 1 row
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    // Only adds pixels that are within the image boundaries
                    if (k >= 0 && l >= 0 && k < height && l < width)
                    {
                        sum_blue += temp[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                        sum_green += temp[k][l].rgbtGreen;
                        sum_red += temp[k][l].rgbtRed;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Use the averages from the surrounding pixels and set the new colour values for the iterated pixel
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sum_blue / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sum_green / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sum_red / count);
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    // Make copy of image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Sobel Operator matrices for Gx and Gy
    int kernel_Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int kernel_Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    // Iterate through the height or also known as each row
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Iterate through the width or also known as each pixel/column
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Initialize values for weighted sums in the x direction
            double gx_blue = 0;
            double gx_green = 0;
            double gx_red = 0;
            // Initialize values for weighted sums in the y direction
            double gy_blue = 0;
            double gy_green = 0;
            double gy_red = 0;
            // Counter to detect what row of the 3x3 the loop is iterating
            int row = 0;

            // Loop to check the surrounding pixels within 1 row
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                // Counter to detect what column of the 3x3 grid the loop is iterating
                int column = 0;
                // Loop to check the surrounding pixels within 1 column
                for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                {
                    // Only adds pixels that are within the image boundaries
                    if (k >= 0 && l >= 0 && k < height && l < width)
                    {
                        // Calculate Gx
                        gx_blue += (kernel_Gx[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtBlue);
                        gx_green += (kernel_Gx[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtGreen);
                        gx_red += (kernel_Gx[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtRed);
                        // Calculate Gy
                        gy_blue += (kernel_Gy[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtBlue);
                        gy_green += (kernel_Gy[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtGreen);
                        gy_red += (kernel_Gy[row][column] * temp[k][l].rgbtRed);
                    }
                    column++;
                }
                row++;
            }
            // Combine Gx and Gy
            int sobel_blue = round(sqrt(pow(gx_blue, 2) + pow(gy_blue, 2)));
            int sobel_green = round(sqrt(pow(gx_green, 2) + pow(gy_green, 2)));
            int sobel_red = round(sqrt(pow(gx_red, 2) + pow(gy_red, 2)));

            // Set the new colour values for the iterated pixel and cap at 255 if necessary
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (sobel_blue > 255) ? 255 : sobel_blue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (sobel_green > 255) ? 255 : sobel_green;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (sobel_red > 255) ? 255 : sobel_red;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: khoaHyh, why does code use `LONG` instead of `int32_t`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: note the `typedef int32_t  LONG` in one of the files `we were asked not to modify`.)

Answer (score 2):

- I strongly recommend to declare `temp` as `RGBTRIPLE[hight + 2][width + 2]`, and initialize the border pixels to `0, 0, 0`. This would eliminate the need to test for *pixels that are within the image boundaries*.
- Initializing `row` and `column` inside the `for` loop makes it more clear how the are used, and that they go lockstep with `k` and `l` respectively. Consider

  ```
    for (int k = i - 1, row = 0; k <= i + 1; k++, row++)
  ```

  and

  ```
        for (int l = j - 1, column = 0; l <= j + 1; l++, column++)
  ```
- No naked loops please. Every time you feel compelled to add a comment like `Make a copy of image`, consider factoring the applicable code into a properly named function, e.g. `make_copy_of_image(....)`.

  Ditto for `Calculate_Gx` and `Calculate_Gy`. These blocks only differ in which kernel they use. Pass it as a parameter.

  Note that `gx_blue, gx_green, gx_red` are crying to be an `RGBTRIPLE`.

Comment: This was very educational, I appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Bug: Careful how you open**

A common problem when near windows is opening a binary file in text mode.  Avoid end-of-line translations and open in binary.

```
// FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "rb");
```

**Check read success**

If the `fread()` fails, error out.  Also recommend to size to the object and not the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
if (fread(&bf, sizeof bf, 1, inptr) != 1) {
  Handle_error();
}
```

**No need for floating point in averaging**

```
    // double sum_blue = 0;
    long long sum_blue = 0;
    for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
        for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++)
                sum_blue += temp[k][l].rgbtBlue;
                    ...
    // round by adding half the count
    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (sum_blue + count/2)/ count;  
    // image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sum_blue / count);
```

and

```
// int average = round(((double) image[i][j].rgbtBlue + (double) image[i][j].rgbtGreen + (double) image[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3);
int average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 
    image[i][j].rgbtRed + 1) / 3;
```

**User loops vs. `memcpy()`**

Library functions tend to be faster than equivalent user code.

```
RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

// Make a copy of image to preserve original values
//for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
//    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
//        temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
//    }
//}
memcpy(temp, image, sizeof temp);
```